# How to insert button for every row so that the data for that particular row can be duplicated into the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have read through several questions on stackoverflow before asking this. I have very little knowledge on php and mysql so much help is needed.

So, what I needed is to create a button for every table row so that when user hits the "copy" button, the data for that row will be copied into the database. How can I do this?

demotable.php (//EDIT//)

```
    <?php 
    require('connect.php');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM trade_history1 ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    echo "<table border = '1px'>"; // start a table tag in the HTML
    echo "<tr><td>" . "ID" . "</td><td>" . "Date" . "</td><td>" . "Type" . "</td><td>" . "Size" . "</td><td>" . "Currency Pair" . "</td><td>" . "Entry" . "</td><td>" . "Stoploss" . "</td><td>". "Take Profit" . "</td><td>" . "Date Close" . "</td><td>" ."Close" . "</td><td>" ."Profit/Loss"."</td><td>" ."Copy"."</td></tr>" ;  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['date'] . "</td><td>" . $row['type'] . "</td><td>" . $row['size'] ."</td><td>" . $row['currency_pair'] ."</td><td>" . $row['entry'] ."</td><td>" . $row['stoploss'] ."</td><td>" . $row['takeprofit'] ."</td><td>" . $row['dateclose'] ."</td><td>" . $row['close'] ."</td><td>" . $row['profitloss'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
    }
    echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML
    mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
    ?>
    <html>
<a href="copytrade.php?id=$_GET['id]"> View </a>
    </html>
```

copytrade.php

```
<?php

        require ('connect.php');

        $mysqli = new mysqli($database_hostname, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name) or exit("Error connecting to database"); 

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO trade_history1 (size, date, type, currency_pair, entry, stoploss, takeprofit, dateclose,close,profitloss) 
                                      SELECT size, date, type, currency_pair, entry, stoploss, takeprofit, dateclose,close,profitloss
                                      FROM trade_history1
                                      WHERE id = ?"); 


        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id); // 


        $successfullyCopied = $stmt->execute(); 


        $stmt->close();

        $mysqli->close();

?>
```

By the way, whenever I click the "copy button" on demotable.php, the link will be this: `http://localhost/1103242B/demo/copytrade.php?copy=copy`. May I know which part of the code did I missed out or did I do wrongly? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put all your table design in the form tag. And then for each row you have to add a copy link with url something like `http://localhost/1103242B/demo/copytrade.php?id=id`. Here id is the record id from database. You are generating the table above and then in below form you don't have any id reference to `copytrade.php` page.

That way also you can do that but in each row you can put some checkbox and then when user clicks on checkbox set the id in a hidden field inside the form and then you can able to post that id to `copytrade.php`.

Both way it will work.

Try to edit your page like below.

```
<html>
<form method = "GET" action = "copytrade.php">

<?php 
require('connect.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM trade_history1 "; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table border = '1px'>"; // start a table tag in the HTML
echo "<tr><td>" . "ID" . "</td><td>" . "Date" . "</td><td>" . "Type" . "</td><td>" . "Size" . "</td><td>" . "Currency Pair" . "</td><td>" . "Entry" . "</td><td>" . "Stoploss" . "</td><td>". "Take Profit" . "</td><td>" . "Date Close" . "</td><td>" ."Close" . "</td><td>" ."Profit/Loss"."</td><td>" ."Copy"."</td><td>Copy</td></tr>" ;  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['date'] . "</td><td>" . $row['type'] . "</td><td>" . $row['size'] ."</td><td>" . $row['currency_pair'] ."</td><td>" . $row['entry'] ."</td><td>" . $row['stoploss'] ."</td><td>" . $row['takeprofit'] ."</td><td>" . $row['dateclose'] ."</td><td>" . $row['close'] ."</td><td>" . $row['profitloss'] . "</td><td>a href='copytrade.php?id=" .$row['id'].'">copy</a></td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
?>

<input type = "submit" name = "copy" value = "copy"/></form>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I have edited the code for demotable.php. As for id reference, I have tried inserting $id = $_GET['id']; yet there is an error. It states "Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\1103242B\demo\copytrade.php on line 5"

Comment: By the way, the button should be auto generated whenever a user submitted a new row of data.

Comment: You have done it wrong. You have added ?id in form tag. Form tag was fine before. Revert it back as before. Then each table row put a link with href="`copytrade.php?id=$_GET['id']`". And then you can get the id below in your copytrade.php page.